# Manga/manhwa about a boy becoming the demon king

Tags: story-identification, manga

A teenage boy gets transported to hell and becomes the demon king after eating the flesh of the demons and he spends a couple of centuries there, I think it was about 500 years.

Soon he gets fed up with eating only demon flesh and wants to go back to earth, which he does.

When he tries to transport himself, he ends up somewhere else before getting to earth. So he thinks he’s in the right place

When he gets back to earth, he realizes that it’s only been 3-5 years since he’s been gone and things have changed.

It’s very similar to like a gaming system society, everyone has ranks and powers and can transport themselves into an MMORPG simulator type world (I hope that makes sense)

He meets a girl after saving her from some bad guys (on earth) and she brings him home because he’s really confused.

Oh and he really wants to eat something, it’s mentioned a good number of times on the first couple of chapters, like he’s really insistent on it and gets mad at some guy for interrupting his supper and beats the crap out of him

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *[Player Who Returned 10,000 Years Later](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/player-who-returned-10000-years-later)*.

> One day he suddenly found himself in hell. All he had was the desire to live and a predation ability. From the first to the ninth thousand circles of hell, he absorbed dozens, hundreds of thousands of demons. Even the seven great dukes of hell bowed down before him. **Why would you wish to go back?** Doesn’t his highness have everything that’s in Hell? What do I have? **Nothing to eat**, nothing to enjoy! The only things in Hell are the barren lands and terrible demons! “I’m going back.” After ten thousand years he returns to Earth.

The synopsis is a solid match for the question; the main character has been in hell for 10,000 years, eating demons. The demons have no culinary skills at all, so he hasn't eaten any real food the whole time, and particularly wants kimchi stew.

He leaves hell through a portal; this takes him to a forest-like area. He saves a girl there and it is revealed that this isn't earth, but a game-like dungeon area where players go. It's also revealed that the current year is 2023, meaning only 5 years have passed.

The girl he saved takes him to her home and offers him some kimchi stew; a jerk breaks down the wall and harasses her, and spills the stew.

[image: Crying over spilled stew]